# What type of time series model would be good?

Tags: time-series

I am trying to fit a time series model to the following data. It seems to be seasonal. Would an ARIMA model be good?

[image]
Here is the data:

```
Count
```

2
1
4
5
4
8
7
11
4
4
11
7
10
7
0
19
13
13
11
9
8
16
10
12
9
7
21
9
10
6
7
19
18
9
19
15
14
17
9
10
10
13
15
20
15
12
15
16

The numbers are separated by spaces.

Comment: The data do not appear to be the same as the plot.  (Where is the 42 in the data on the plot?  Where is the value of (28,0) on the plot shown in the data?)

Comment: @whuber: The data starts at t=12.

Comment: Usually time is the abscissa and the observed value is the ordinate. You have it switch which I think is what confused whuber.

Comment: @MichaelChernick: Isn't my data correct if we assume the x-axis is time?

Comment: @Damien Yes I realized that and mentioned it in my answer.  I think you have fixed the labelling now.

Comment: @Michael, please plot the data (or look at the plots produced in the answers) and compare that to the plot in the question: they are different.

Comment: @whuber: I edited the data

Comment: Damien, editing the data was a bad idea, because you have already received several detailed responses that used the data you originally posted. It's unfair of you in effect to pull the rug out from under those who have gone to that work to help you.

Comment: @whuber I have realizeed that the lablling of the axes was probably the problem and I think Damien has ffixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure the data you added to your post is the same you used to make the plot. At any rate, it doesn't really matter since we're trying to help with the 
underlying methodological aspect of the problem.

From whatever information we have, i would advise a simple median filter:

The idea is to circumvent the model-fitting procedure as much as possible, since we don't have enough information --and IMHO datapoints-- to build a complicated model.

Edit: Following Whuber's suggestion I've taken the square root transformation to symmetricize the residuals.

looking at the outliers, i don't really see a seasonality --below, for illustration, i'm carrying the analysis using [R, the open source statistical software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29)

```
library("robfilter")
dta<-c(2, 1, 4, 5, 4, 8, 7, 11, 4, 4, 11, 7, 10, 7, 42, 19, 13, 13, 11, 9, 8, 16, 10, 12, 9, 7, 21, 9, 10, 6, 7, 19, 18, 9, 19 ,15, 14, 17, 9, 10 ,10, 13, 15, 20, 15, 12, 15, 16 ,20, 17, 21 ,19, 8, 16, 11, 12, 16, 10, 5, 18, 13, 18, 16, 7, 12, 12, 17, 17, 7, 14, 15 ,10, 13, 15, 11, 13, 10, 9, 11, 11 ,10, 8, 24, 13, 18, 8, 8 ,13, 9 ,7, 6, 14, 17 ,7, 13, 9, 11, 19, 8 ,9, 13, 11, 14, 5, 8, 8, 13, 12 ,20, 9, 18 ,13, 13, 10 ,6 ,9, 8, 8)
mod4a<-robreg.filter(y=sqrt(dta),width=12,method="MED",h=7,minNonNAs=5,online=TRUE,extrapolate=FALSE)
resds<-abs(c(rep(sqrt(dta[1]),11),na.omit(mod4a$level[,1]))-sqrt(dta))
mod4b<-robreg.filter(y=resds,width=12,method="MED",h=7,minNonNAs=5,online=TRUE,extrapolate=FALSE)
otl<-which(resds/mod4b$level[,1]>3) #time of the outliers:
>otl
[1]  15  32  53  59  83  85 104 109
```

[image: fit of the series, with outliers marked in green]

Comment: This is the right idea, because (a) there is a trend but it's not easily characterized and (b) there are no significant serial correlations at any lag.  However, loess will do a much better job than a median filter at *characterizing* these data. All this begs the question of *why* the OP is fitting the data: median filters or loess will do little for predicting future values, for instance.

Comment: @whuber: --this is a one sided filter: as far as i understood the option "online" makes sure it doesn't use  data from $t+i$, $i>0$ at time $t$. More generally, I agree with you: I also tough of asking the OP what was the end purpose (is he, for example, interested in the value of an  ar coefficient for a given lag)?

Comment: @user602: I want to predict data

Comment: Good point about the potential online nature (+1). Another mild improvement can be achieved by analyzing the square roots of the data (because these evidently are counts). Alternatively--for sophisticated analysts--a Poisson GLM with splines or changepoints would do a fine job.

Comment: @Damien: yes, as long as you use "online=TRUE" this approach can be used for forecasting (we only use the past). The final forcast for the next period is 11...not very different from IrishStats's forcast.

Comment: @Damien The AUTOBOX forecast is 10.8572 ( the robust/outlier adjusted mean of the last 44 values )

Comment: @user603: Where is the final forecast for the next period?

Comment: @Damien: it's the last entry of mod4a$level[,1] raised to the power 2 -- since this is based on a model for the square root of your data--.

Comment: @user603: Also I don't see how i have >100 data points. I only had 37 data points

Comment: @user603: Sorry I realized that you were working off of the old data which had more data.

Comment: @user603: This has 47 and I just used your example for it. Thanks: 2 1 4 5 4 8 7 11 4 4 11 7 10 7 0 19 13 13 11 9 8 16 10 12 9 7 21 9 10 6 7 19 18 9 19 15 14 17 9 10 10 13 15 20 15 12 15 16

Comment: it had 48, and the next period forecast would be 14.5 :). But you can do the whole analysis for yourself: R is open source, free and so is the robfilter library and furthermore the methodology is fully explained in the peer reviewed papers referenced in the package's documentations. In a word, it's not a black box and your are encouraged to play with it.

Comment: @user602: It seems that all the value in mod4a$level[,1] are the square root of the forecasted values up to the last data point we have. But if we wanted to extrapolate, we could just change extrapolate = TRUE to get the next prediction?

Comment: @Damien: no: extrapolate=TRUE only concerns the data for which we don't have a model. Since online is TRUE, the extrapolation only affects the first 11 observations for which we don't have a model --and which would otherwise be coded as NA--.

Comment: @user603: How would we get the next predicted observation after the last observed one? What about the next one after that....etc...? 14.5 is just the predicted value at t=48. But we already have observed this value. What about the predicted value at t=49?

Comment: @Damien: as with all models that allow level shifts, there is no simple linear expression for $y_{t+k}|y_t$: you have to recursively fit the forecast in the model to get a new forecast. After 12 periods the forecast will be a constant.because the model only uses the last 12 observations to build a forecast. This is the "width" parameter. But again, this is pretty simple to do in R from the code i posted (it's just a loop).

Comment: @user603: The model uses 1-12 to get 13, 2-13 to get 14, etc...?

Comment: yes. But again, you are encouraged to go read the references quoted in the [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robfilter/robfilter.pdf)

Comment: @user603: Would you say median filters are good to detect any violations of apparent trends in a dataset?

Comment: @Damien: i'm not even sure what the question means. The important property of the recursive median in this context is that it bulges very little [--minimally among all estimator of central tendency, in fact--](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS/Repository/1.0/Disseminate?view=body&id=pdf_1&handle=euclid.aoms/1177703732), when up to width/2-1 of the last width observations have been replaced by arbitrarily data.

Comment: @user602: So we are using 36 windows of size 12 to get the forecasts. To get the projected values for the next 10 time periods, we would need to use 46 windows?

Comment: No: but i think you are confused about basic time series stuff. Try to look for "moving window estimation". Otherwise ask a separate questions.

Answer (score 2):

1. delete the leading zeroes as they can inflate the autocorrelation function
2. a visual suggest possibly a level shift and then a slight upward trend
3. a few anomalies , maybe just one , (pulses)
4. no apparent seasonal structure.

An ARIMA model would be good just as long as the reflections above were considered.

If you want to post the data , I will be more specific as to the applicability of ARIMA.

The 114 values you posted are quite different from your original plot. The actual-fit-forecast is[image]. The acf of the original series shows little structure [image] . The "best model" contains no ARIMA structure but evidences a few unusual data points and three distinct means or GROUPS [1-32 ; 33-69 ; 70-114 ] [image] with outliers [image: enter image description here] .[4] . The acf of the residuals suggests randomness![enter image description here] . What we have here are three arima models of the form (0,0,0)(0,0,0) with three different means or regimes XBAR1=8.0 ; XBAR2=14.826 and XBAR3=10.8572. One could consider this single-dimension cluster analysis (see [Univariate clustering of time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30361/univariate-clustering-of-time-series/32279#32279)  )

Comment: Can I email you the data?

Comment: Damien, because that kind of personal communication circumvents the purpose and mechanisms of this site it is *strongly discouraged.*

Comment: @Damien: Consider providing a public Dropbox (or equivalent) link instead.

Comment: @IrishStat I see from your plot that Huber was right. his data looks nothing like the original plot even if the labelling was corrected. It does look like two level shifts with no apparent trend at all. there is one very distinctive outlier in the first portion of the series and possbly another after the second shift. My suggestions wouldn't work for this plot. Mine only pertained as possibilities to the original plot. If there was an issue with the private communication i think it is resolved as you have exhibited the data and your modeling of it very nicely for CV.

Comment: @IrishStat it looks to me that the level shifts explain a lot of the variation,  The remaining problems are the outliers and the job for the OP to come up with a sensible explanation for the apparent behavior.

Comment: The data are counts and ARMA models are not good choice to analyze them (even after transforming the data). It's better to use generalized ARMA (GLARMA) models.

Answer (score 0):

It would also help if you set your data as a time-series such as:

## 1. Make a R timeseries out of the rawdata: specify frequency & startdate

gIIP <- ts(Trimmer, frequency=12, start=c(2005,11))
print(gIIP)
plot.ts(gIIP, type="l", col="blue", ylab="Title of Chart", lwd=2,
        main="Full data")
grid()

Comment: This seems to be code declaring a time series and plotting it. That's already been done.

Comment: Operating on time-series (ts) objects in R is useful advice, indeed, but this answer doesn't address the OP's question(s) at all.