# Finding anomalies using moving average in a time series

Tags: time-series, outliers

I want to find anomalies in a time series. Is it possible to find anomalies using moving average?

Comment: no, but with some [running median](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30362/603) it should be possible

Answer (score 1):

Anomalies can be easily detected while using "moving averages" . Please review the woRk or Tsay http://www.unc.edu/~jbhill/tsay.pdf . You might also search for "AUTOMATIC DETECTION OF INTERVENTION VARIABLES" using Google . Post your actual data and I will post the results.

Comment: Hi sir, thank you for your answer, I have a very long time series (about 10000 integere values). Im am not sure, if I can attach the file here.  Which method do you find better to find anomalies? FFT, Wavlet transform or moving average- Is there any difference between anmolay and outlier in time series?

Comment: Post the data to dropbox.com.  Check out Ruey Tsay's paper on outliers www.unc.edu/~jbhill/tsay.pdf‎